Openvpn Connect auto connection
this is my first time posting something here and i really need some help with something i'm working on.
so this is a code i'm tryin to import a .ovpn profile, but it appears that it is not connecting to the imported profile automatically.
i'm tryin to run this script on my powershell so that i can automate the connection to my vpn. i have tried everything even third party to help me access buttons within openvpn Connect but nothing worked. can someone please let me know how could i solve this using powershell script and i really appreciate it.
param (
    [string]$OvpnProfilePath,
    [string]$DisplayName
)

# Specify the path to the OpenVPN Connect executable
$openVpnConnectExecutable = "$Env:Programfiles\OpenVPN Connect\OpenVPNConnect.exe"

# Get the script directory
$scriptRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$OvpnProfilePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptRoot -ChildPath "steros_steros@steroscloud.openvpn.com_[Paris].ovpn"

# Specify the path to the log file for OpenVPN Connect
$openVpnLogFilePath = Join-Path -Path C:\Users\client\Desktop -ChildPath "OpenVpnConnectLog.txt"

# Logging
$logFilePath = Join-Path -Path C:\Users\client\Desktop -ChildPath "IntuneScriptLog.txt"
Start-Transcript -Path $logFilePath -Append

try {
    Write-Host "Executing script from: $scriptRoot"

    # Set the working directory to the script directory
    Set-Location -Path $scriptRoot

    # Check if OpenVPN Connect executable exists
    if (-not (Test-Path $openVpnConnectExecutable -PathType Leaf)) {
        Write-Host "Error: OpenVPN Connect executable not found at $openVpnConnectExecutable"
        exit 1
    }

    # Check if the OpenVPN profile file exists
    

    # Check if OpenVPN Connect is already running
    $openVpnProcess = Get-Process -Name "openvpnconnect" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($openVpnProcess -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "OpenVPN Connect is running. Closing OpenVPN Connect..."
        Stop-Process -Name "openvpnconnect" -Force
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5  # Allow time for the process to close
    }

    # Start OpenVPN Connect and import the profile, redirecting both output streams to the same log file
    $processStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $processStartInfo.FileName = $openVpnConnectExecutable
    $processStartInfo.Arguments = "--import-profile=$OvpnProfilePath --name=steros@steroscloud.openvpn.com"
    $processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true

    $process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($processStartInfo)
    $output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $errorOutput = $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    $process.WaitForExit()

    # Log the output to the OpenVpnConnectLog.txt file
    $output + $errorOutput | Out-File -FilePath $openVpnLogFilePath -Encoding UTF8

    # Check if the import was successful
    if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0) {
        # Create success indicator file
        $successFilePath = Join-Path -Path C:\Users\client\Desktop -ChildPath "OpenVpn-SuccessIndicator.txt"
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $successFilePath -Force | Out-Null
        Write-Host "OpenVPN profile imported successfully. Display Name: $DisplayName"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failed to import OpenVPN profile. Display Name: $DisplayName"
    }

    # Start OpenVPN Connect
    Start-Process -FilePath $openVpnConnectExecutable
    Write-Host "OpenVPN Connect has been launched."
    

} catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
} finally {
    # Logging
    Stop-Transcript
}

my quuestion is: how can i autoconnect whenever i import the desired profile using powershell script or whenever i run this script? does openvpn connect interact with powershell? because as far as my knowledge goes openvpn connect does not support commands to help connect directly to a desired profile. i forgot to mention that i'm using OPENVPN CONNECT v3

You forgot to ask a question :)
